# Need help understanding hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value

I have the following question:

> Let $X_{i}$ be Gaussian random variables with $\mu$ = 10 and
>   $\sigma^{2}$ = 1. We decide to use the test statistic $\hat{\mu}$ =
>   $\frac{1}{20}\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_{i}$ and following tests:
>
> $|\hat{\mu}-10|>\tau$ : Reject $H_{0}$
>
> $|\hat{\mu}-10|\leq \tau$ : Cannot reject $H_{0}$
>
> 1) Find $\tau$ if you want to have 95% confidence in the test.
>
> 2) You find that $\hat{\mu}=10.588$. Do you reject $H_{0}$? If so,
>   what is the p-value?
>
> Using textbook equations, I found out that for
>
> 1) $\tau$ = 1.96$\sigma_{\hat{\mu}}$ = $1.96 \sqrt{\frac{1}{20}}$ = 0.392
>
> 2) |10.588-10| = 0.588 > 0.392 $\rightarrow$ Reject $H_{0}$
>
> p-value = 0.003

What I'm looking for is explanation or intuition as to why this is the answer? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $95\%$ [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for $\mu$ is:
$$\hat{\mu}-z_{\alpha/2}\cdot \sigma_{\hat{\mu}}<\mu<\hat{\mu}+z_{\alpha/2}\cdot \sigma_{\hat{\mu}} \iff \\
\hat{\mu}-1.96\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}<\mu<\hat{\mu}+1.96\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \iff \\
-1.96\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}<\mu-\hat{\mu}<1.96\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \iff \\
|\mu-\hat{\mu}|<1.96\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=\tau=1.96\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{20}}=0.392 \ \text{or}\\
\hat{\mu}-0.392<\mu<\hat{\mu}+0.392$$
It implies that we are $95\%$ confident that the population mean will lie within $0.392$ distance from $\hat{\mu}$. The null hypothesis states to reject if it is greater distance. With $\hat{\mu}=10.588$, it is greater distance, so we reject $H_0$.

$p$-value is:
$$\mathbb P\left(z>\frac{\hat{\mu}-\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)=\mathbb P\left(z>\frac{10.588-10}{1/\sqrt{20}}\right)=\mathbb P(z>2.62962)=0.004<0.025 \Rightarrow \ \text{Reject $H_0$}.$$ 
Reference: WA [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P(z%3E0.588%2F(1%2Fsqrt(20)))).

Comment: Implication of the CI does not say that we are 95% confident about so and so.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, right, it says that we are 95% confident that the interval contains the true mean. Because, the true mean is a fixed number, so no chance associated with it, but with the samples chosen.